# Calculating $\sin 45^\circ$ two ways gives $1/\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{1/2}/1$. What went wrong?

Tags: trigonometry

In a right triangle, relative to a $45^\circ$ angle, if we have 
$$\text{adjacent} = 1$$
$$\text{opposite} = 1$$

then
$$\text{hypotenuse}=\sqrt{o^2+a^2}=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$$
so that
$$\sin 45^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

But, when 
$$\text{hypotenuse} = 1$$
$$\text{opposite} = \text{adjacent}$$ 
then (writing $o$ for $\text{opposite}$ and $a$ for $\text{adjacent}$)
$$\begin{align}
o &= \sqrt{h^2-a^2} = \sqrt{1^2-o^2} \\[4pt]
\implies \quad o^2 &= h^2-o^2\\
&=1-o^2 \\[4pt]
\implies\quad 2o^2&=1 \\
\implies\quad o&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}$$
so that
$$\sin 45^\circ =\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}{1}$$

What went wrong?

Comment: Nothing went wrong.

Comment: Actually it is $\sqrt {\frac 12}=\frac 1{\sqrt2}=\frac {\sqrt2}2$

Comment: Nothing went wrong, those two expressions are two of many ways to write the same number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing went wrong. 
$$ \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}{1} = \sqrt{\frac12}=\frac1{\sqrt2} $$

Comment: ok, but 
$$sin(45) = 0.8509035245341184$$ 
and 
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} = 0.7071067811865476$$

Why the difference?

Comment: No, $\sin(45)\approx 0.8509$ only because you are calculating the sine of $45$ radians. $\sin(45^\circ)$ is indeed $0.7071$.

Comment: dope. thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have the square root of 1/2. Separate the entire square root into the square root of the numerator and the denominator and second result is identical to your first result!